# Blurring a UIView that contains the keyboard with content beneath it (iOS 7)

Tags: ios, uiview, ios7, uikeyboard, uigraphicscontext

I have a UIView with a UITableView the extends beneath the keyboard. The content in the table view is bright enough, making it clear that content sits behind the keyboard. I'm attempting to take a screenshot of the entire view in order to blur it using the following code:

```
- (UIImage *)screenshotFromView:(UIView *)view;
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, NO, 0.0);
    [view drawViewHierarchyInRect:view.bounds afterScreenUpdates:NO];

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```

However, the image that is returned does not create a transparent keyboard. This presents an odd transition when going from the non-blurred view to the blurred view, since there is clearly content behind the keyboard before the transition to the blurred image.

Is it possible to take a screenshot of the entire screen, without use of private APIs, while still keeping the transparency of the keyboard + the status bar?

Comment: Can you clarify, you want to take a screenshot of the screen -keyboard included- in order to blur it ? Is it to display it after before closing the app to blur important informations so they won't be visible in multitasking panel ?

Answer (score 2):

I got the exact problem as you these days, so I exactly know what you want. I wanted the whole UI blurred behind a message including the keyboard, which is not included with any regular screenshot method. My cure is the following code:

```
- (UIImage*)screenShotWithKeyboard:(UIView *)viewToShoot
{
    UIWindow *keyboard = nil;
    for (UIWindow *window in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows])
    {
        if ([[window description] hasPrefix:@"<UITextEffectsWin"])
        {
            keyboard = window;
            break;
        }
    }

    // Define the dimensions of the screenshot you want to take (the entire screen in this case)
    CGSize size =  [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;

    // Create the screenshot
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);

    CGContextRef context=UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // delete following line if you only want the keyboard
    [[viewToShoot layer] renderInContext:context];

    if(keyboard!=nil)
        [[keyboard layer] renderInContext:context];

    UIImage *screenImg = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return screenImg;
}
```

I got the idea from an article of [Aran Balkan](http://aralbalkan.com/3573/) I broke it down to one method and testet it for iOS 7 which seems to work for me. The article worth reading as he explain the tricks behind a little. As you only want the actual keyboard as image, you can comment out the line I marked in the code. With that image keyboard you can do your blur stuff yourself. 
The code is far from perfect, but I think you got the idea.

Two thinks at the end:
I am a freshman to objective c and iOS development. If you find any problematic bugs, a comment is very welcome to improve this answer.
Second, I wrote this code today in my app and I do not know yet if I violate any developer rules for iOS. At the moment I do not see any problems, but I will investigate this further as I want to release my app with that graphic trick. I will keeping this post updated. Until than, as with point one, I would highly appreciate any comment regarding this issue.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Martin! Although the above code captures the keyboard, it unfortunately doesn't capture the transparency of the keyboard. So if there is any kind of colorful content behind the content, the blur transition will continue to look awkward -- in that it appears as though the colorful content is removed during the blur.

Comment: @bdev Yeah, looks like I was so happy to help that I did not understand your real problem. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [`UIKeyboardAppearanceDark`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006896-CH3-SW31)? Currently the default value of [`keyboardAppearance`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfp/UITextInputTraits/keyboardAppearance) corresponds to `UIKeyboardAppearanceLight`, so it may not be suited to your use case.

Comment: Yes, the problem I'm experiencing actually occurs when using UIKeyboardAppearanceDark. The problem is that I'm unable to capture the transparency of the keyboard during a screenshot.